# Sum of tensor products of positive roots of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $\Delta^+$ denote a choice of positive roots for the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(n)$.

The Weyl vector, $\rho$, is half the sum of the positive roots
\begin{equation}
  2\rho = \sum_{\beta \in \Delta^+} \beta \,.
\end{equation}

Similarly, the Cartan matrix, $A$, can be written as
\begin{equation}
  nA = \sum_{\beta \in \Delta^+} \beta \otimes \beta \,.
\end{equation}

What is known about the general case:
\begin{equation}
  C_K = \sum_{\beta \in \Delta^+} \underbrace{\beta \otimes \cdots \otimes \beta}_K \, ?
\end{equation}
Are the $C_K$ related to other, perhaps better known, objects? Particular $K$-tensors in $\mathfrak{su}(n)$? I am especially interested in the case where $K = 3$.